# Codeigniter joins for multiple tables

Tags: codeigniter, join

Hi I have 6 tables with

I Want to get all details in courses booked table and related with all other tables and i have a where condition which is tutor id could any one help me how to join those tables and how to get result

Comment: Have you looked into codeigniter join http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add as many joins as you need, like

```
$this->db->select('t.name tutor, s.name student, c.course_name couse, tts.time_slot')->from('tutor t');
$this->db->join('tutor_courses tc', 'tc.tutor_id = t.id', 'right');
$this->db->join('tutor_time_slots tt', 'tt.tutor_id = t.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('courses_booked cb', 'cb.tutor_time_slot_id = tt.id');
$this->db->join('student s', 'cb.sudent_id = s.id');
```

This is an example, try it and tell me if it run